# How to return model with relationsip in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have two model **Product** and **Category**.

The `categories` table have **id**, and **name** columns.

While the `products` table have **id**, **name**, and **category_id** [*foreign_key to category*].

---

Here is my below code (already have category with values of 1, "School Supply"):

```
$product = new Product;
$product->category_id = 1;
$product->name = "pencil";
$product->save();

return $product->with('category');
```

My question is why it returns an error below when I try to get the data with the relation model? Someone knows how to do it exactly?

> [34;4mIlluminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder[39;24m {#4069}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lazy eager load the relations using `load` method instead of `with`.

`with` is used for eager loading.

```
$product->load('category');
return $product;
```